# XML query using multiple operators (Few Ands and or for status field)

Tags: xml, caml

I need to fetch all the record where docID is 555, Request Type contains Modify, and status is not complete or status is not rejected. I tried following but it returned data has has "rejected" in status column.

SharePoint list CAML query using multiple operators (Few Ands and or for status field)

```
<Query>
   <Where>
      <And>
         <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='DocID' />
            <Value Type="Text">{ItemProperty:DocID}</Value>
         </Eq>
         <And>
            <Contains>
                <FieldRef Name="RequestType"  />
                <Value Type="Choice">Modify</Value>               
            </Contains>
            <Or>
               <Neq>
                  <FieldRef Name="Change_x0020_Approved"  />
                  <Value Type="Text">Complete</Value>
               </Neq>
               <Neq>
                  <FieldRef Name="Change_x0020_Approved"  />
                  <Value Type="Text">Rejected</Value>                   
               </Neq>
            </Or>
         </And>
      </And>
   </Where>
</Query>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the following CAML does what I need. The funny thing I am not using OR operator but it works.

```
  <Where>
    <And>
      <And>
        <And>
          <And>
            <Contains>
              <FieldRef Name='RequestType' />
              <Value Type='Choice'>Modify</Value>
            </Contains>
            <Eq>
              <FieldRef Name='DocID' />
              <Value Type='Text'>555</Value>
            </Eq>
          </And>
          <IsNotNull>
            <FieldRef Name='Change_x0020_Approved' />
          </IsNotNull>
        </And>
        <Neq>
          <FieldRef Name='Change_x0020_Approved' />
          <Value Type='Text'>Complete</Value>
        </Neq>
      </And>
      <Neq>
        <FieldRef Name='Change_x0020_Approved' />
        <Value Type='Text'>Rejected</Value>
      </Neq>
    </And>
  </Where>
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition "A is not 3 or A is not 4" is true for all values of A, including the values 3 and 4. I suspect you meant "A is not 3 and A is not 4".